# Spring JMS and parameterized types (@JmsListener with e.g. List<String> argument)?

Tags: generics, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I want to be able to send e.g. a value of type `List<String>` using `JmsTemplate.convertAndSent(...)` and then receive it with a method annotated with `@JmsListener` that takes an argument of type `List<String>`.

However it seems that the default approach of storing the message payload type as a message property doesn't support generics.

If I look in `MappingJackson2MessageConverter.getJavaTypeForMessage(Message)` I see:

```
Class<?> typeClass = ClassUtils.forName(typeId, this.beanClassLoader);
return this.objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(typeClass);
```

So it looks like one can only get from `typeId` to a `Class<?>` and that there's no way to get to an instance of `ParameterizedType`.

Is there some clever way of mixing in type parameter information that I'm missing here? E.g. somehow using `ParameterizedTypeReference`?

Answer (score 1):

The best I've been able to do is to create a subclass of my parameterized type on the sending side. E.g. I have:

```
public class StringList extends ArrayList<String> {
    public StringList(Collection<String> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    // Empty constructor needed by Jackson.
    public StringList() { }
}
```

Then in my sending logic I have:

```
template.convertAndSend("my-destination", new StringList(myList));
```

I.e. I have to convert my `List<String>` into a `StringList` so that the outgoing message will be tagged with the type `StringList`.

Then on the receiving side I can pretend `StringList` doesn't exist and just use `List<String>` like so:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "my-destination")
public void consumerList(List<String> list) { ... }
```

I.e. Jackson creates an instance of `StringList` under the covers but I consume it as `List<String>`.

This isn't too awful - but it'd be nicer if it wasn't necessary to create the `StringList` subclass of `List` (and then copy the contents of my real list into an instance of `StringList`).